# Automatic sequnetial numbering of folders and files

Tags: spfx

We have a request to enable a type of automatic number of files and folders in our sharepoint libraries so that they look similar to the below image.  So the actual name of the file and folder won't change, it will be a new column that shows the numbering (these can be merged if needed to display nicely).  We could also do with them automatically changing and updating if documnets are moved to different folders.

This will be built using SPFx (react or not) so that we can give the users a button to add files and folders.  We would also like to create something that would go through existing doc libraries and apply the numbering.

I don't know of any built in feature to Sharepoint that will do this (if anyone has ever used a system called HighQ, this has an inbuilt function for this which we want to replicate).

Has anyone done this or can they suggest a way to do it?

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks

[image]